# import inside Jest manual mock (in __mocks__) is sometimes undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs, integration-testing

I'm wanting to use the Firebase Firestore emulator in my Jest mock for integration tests. My `src/__mocks__/firebase.ts` is:

```js
import mockFirebase from '@firebase/testing'

console.log(mockFirebase)

export const firebase = mockFirebase.initializeAdminApp({
  projectId: `autoflocc-${process.pid}`,
})

export const db = firebase.firestore()
```

It's imported in the test code like follows:

```js
import mockFirebase from '@firebase/testing'
jest.mock('../src/firebase')
```

However, when the mock file runs `mockFirebase` is `undefined` (as per the `console.log`). I've tried importing other modules and some work (`import _ from 'lodash'`) but others do not (`import x from 'firebase-functions'`), also returning `undefined`.

Any ideas why some imports work in manual mocks but not others?

Note: this is Typescript, which might be affecting it.

Comment: One thing which can cause Jest mocks to import as undefined is if you have circular imports in your app. Jest.mock will hoist code to the top of the file, and if you have circular imports jest can get very confused. Make sure you seperate out your code enough to avoid any circular imports.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax:

```
import mockFirebase from '@firebase/testing';
```

...is trying to import the [`default` export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#default-exports) of `@firebase/testing` as `mockFirebase`...

...but `mockFirebase` ends up `undefined` because `@firebase/testing` [doesn't have a `default` export](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/6e90afc0142355999196557a6be2be3fe2704824/packages/testing/index.ts#L24-L35).

---

The correct syntax to import everything in `@firebase/testing` would be:

```
import * as mockFirebase from '@firebase/testing';
```

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the same result: `import * as mockFirebase from '@firebase/testing'; mockFirebase.initializeAdminApp({...})` results in: `TypeError: mockFirebase.initializeAdminApp is not a function` because `initializeAdminApp` is undefined.

Comment: Further to that, when I console log out mockFirebase (when imported from *) then `database` and `firestore` are undefined but `apps` and everything else is defined. It's like that module is only partially initialized when I import it.

Comment: I can get around that issue, but calling `mockFirebase.initializeAdminApp(...)` inside a function (not at the top level of a module) now dies with `TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function`. `firebase.initializeApp(...)` is code in the `@firebase/testing` package, not mine. So even modules `@firebase/testing` has imported are undefined.